# Google BigQuery Error: "code": 501, "message": "Not Implemented: Cannot cancel a job of this type"

Tags: copy, google-bigquery

I'm getting the following error when trying to cancel a (not too big, 2.6 GB copy) job in BigQuery:

```
    {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notImplemented",
    "message": "Not Implemented: Cannot cancel a job of this type"
   }
  ],
  "code": 501,
  "message": "Not Implemented: Cannot cancel a job of this type"
 }
}
```

The status of the job is the following:

```
 "status": {
  "state": "RUNNING"
 }
```

I also can't delete the table it's copying from (what kind of makes sense), but without an error message. I can click 'Delete table', but nothing happens.

Did someone encounter the same problem or has someone a solution for this? It's running for an hour now and I need to go on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy table jobs cannot be cancelled (this is what error message is saying). But BigQuery is going to implement support for copying table cancellation soon. In the meantime, if you could share the job id of the query, the BigQuery team can investigate why this particular one got stuck.